# Colored margin with vertical text

Tags: color, margins

What I'd like to reproduce on LaTeX can be seen on the picture below.

I am writing my master thesis (book style) and I'd like to add a colored margin on every page (on the right for the right pages and on the left for the left pages) with the chapter name written vertically in it as well as the page number.

I didn't find any solution on Google so your help is very welcome.

[image: What I'd like to reproduce]

## Edit after Gonzalo Medina's response (see below)

Here is my code

```
% !TEX encoding = IsoLatin
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1.5ex} % Set the length of skip below the caption


\usepackage{chngpage} %Allows for temporary adjustment of side margins when the tables are to wide


% Just makes the table prettier (see \toprule, \bottomrule, etc. commands below)
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow} % multirows in tables

% Dimensions of the page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[papersize={210mm,210mm},top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subfigure}

% For the lateral stripe 
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{colortbl,hhline}


\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection .\alph{subsubsection}}

% ========== Table of contents ========== 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks, % emp?É¬É?Ç¬©cher latex de colorer les liens
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black, % couleur des liens dans la table des matières
    urlcolor=blue
}

% Dots in the TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % Ligne of dots in the TOC
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at begin picture={
   \shorthandoff{:;!?};}
}}

% Give the same layout than the chapters to the TOC 
 \makeatletter
\def\@cftmaketoctitle{\chapter*{\contentsname}}
\makeatother
%___________________________________________

% ========== No number to the "part" pages ==========
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother
%___________________________________________


% ========== Layout of the chapters ==========

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
% ----- Case without "\chapter{}" -----
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \newpage 
  \mbox{~}     
  \vfill %
    {\parindent \z@ \reset@font
            \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    %\vspace*{1\p@}%
    \color{orange}{\hrulefill}
    \par\nobreak
    %\vskip 100\p@
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  }
  % Vertical stripe
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[orange]
  (current page.north east)
    rectangle
  ([xshift=-\StripeWd]current page.south east);
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north west,
  font=\ChapterFont,
  rotate=-90
]
  at ([xshift=-0.4\StripeWd,yshift=-\ChapterShift]current page.north east)
  {\leftmark};
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north,
  font=\PageFont,
]
  at ([xshift=-0.5\StripeWd,yshift=\PageShift]current page.south east)
  {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
    \newpage
}

% ----- Case with "\chapter*{}" -----
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \newpage 
  \mbox{~}     
  \vfill %
    {\parindent \z@ \reset@font
            \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    %\vspace*{1\p@}%
    \color{orange}{\hrulefill}
    \par\nobreak
    %\vskip 100\p@
  }
% Vertical stripe
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[orange]
  (current page.north east)
    rectangle
  ([xshift=-\StripeWd]current page.south east);
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north west,
  font=\ChapterFont,
  rotate=-90
]
  at ([xshift=-0.4\StripeWd,yshift=-\ChapterShift]current page.north east)
  {\leftmark};
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north,
  font=\PageFont,
]
  at ([xshift=-0.5\StripeWd,yshift=\PageShift]current page.south east)
  {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
}

%___________________________________________

% ========== Vertical stripe to every page ==========
% Vertical stripe to every page of a chapter except the first page, with the name of the chapter and the page number written in it
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newlength\ChapterShift
\newlength\PageShift
\newlength\StripeWd

% the vertical shift for the chapter title from the upper border of the page
\setlength\ChapterShift{2cm}
% the vertical shift for the page number from the lower border of the page
\setlength\PageShift{2cm}
% the width of the vertical stripe
\setlength\StripeWd{2cm}

% the color of the stripe
\colorlet{StripeColor}{gray!60}

% the font for chapter title in the stripe
\def\ChapterFont{\color{white}\Large\sffamily}
% the font for page number in the stripe
\def\PageFont{\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}{}}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[OR]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[StripeColor]
  (current page.north east)
    rectangle
  ([xshift=-\StripeWd]current page.south east);
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north west,
  font=\ChapterFont,
  rotate=-90
]
  at ([xshift=-0.4\StripeWd,yshift=-\ChapterShift]current page.north east)
  {\leftmark};
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north,
  font=\PageFont,
]
  at ([xshift=-0.5\StripeWd,yshift=\PageShift]current page.south east)
  {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[EL]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[StripeColor]
  (current page.north west)
    rectangle
  ([xshift=\StripeWd]current page.south west);
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=south east,
  font=\ChapterFont,
  rotate=90
]
  at ([xshift=0.6\StripeWd,yshift=-\ChapterShift]current page.north west)
  {\leftmark};
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north,
  font=\PageFont,
]
  at ([xshift=0.5\StripeWd,yshift=\PageShift]current page.south west)
  {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

%___________________________________________




\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\title{Title page}

\maketitle


\newpage
\hfill
\vfill
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm} r}
Avant toute chose, je tiens à remercier sincèrement ma co-promotrice, Madame Bernadette Merenne; et mon promoteur, Monsieur Pierre Frankignoulle; pour leur disponibilité, leur implication, leurs nombreux conseils et l'attention qu'ils ont portés à ce travail. \newline

J'adresse également mes remerciements à toutes les personnes qui m'ont aidée de près ou de loin dans la réalisation de mes recherches et dans le travail d'analyse et de synthèse de mes différentes interviews.\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Monsieur Tielman et Madame Roosen pour leurs multiples interventions;
\item Les lecteurs de ce mémoire pour avoir accepté cette tâche;
\item Les nombreuses personnes interrogées pour leur implication et leur enthousiasme;
\item Ma famille et mes amis qui m'ont aidée et soutenue durant l'élaboration de ce travail.
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}


\newpage
 \tableofcontents
  \markboth{TABLE DES MATIERES}{}

\newpage 

\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{INTRODUCTION}{}
\section*{Motivation}

\lipsum[1-5]

\section*{Objectif}


\section*{Méthodologie}
\subsection*{Sujet}


\subsection*{Manière de procéder} 


\newpage 
\empty

\part{}
\chapter{Mobilité et aménagement, un problème croissant}

\section{Quelques définitions}

\subsection{Mobilité}


\subsection{Développement urbain}

\section{Un peu d'histoire}

Le couple agglomération - réseau viaire ne date pas d'aujourd'hui. Un grand nombre de villages et villes se sont développés à la croisée de voies de communication; points d'échanges marchands, culturels, intellectuels, etc.\\

Au cours du XIXe siècle, la création des tramways et la pénétration du chemin de fer favorisent un développement de l'espace urbain à proximité des points d'arrêts de leurs lignes respectives. L'espace public reste en lien avec l'échelle du piéton. La banlieue, qui était déjà présente avant l'ère de l'automobile, se déployait en effet en fonction des axes de transport en commun. La ville demeurait compacte; son étendue était plutôt réduite et sa fonction principalement un lieu d'habitation dense et multifonctionnel. \\

En Belgique, à la fin du XIXe siècle, les chemins de fer vicinaux ont encouragé la construction de logements à l'extérieur des grandes villes et ont densifié un grand nombre de petits villages existants.\\

Après la guerre, l'expansion de l'automobile a contribué à l'étalement des villes en favorisant la fragmentation  du territoire et à la dispersion des diverses activités. Ce phénomène donne naissance à la ville diffuse avec la création de tracés routiers conçus sur base d'une hiérarchisation des voies de circulation.\\

Rapidement des problèmes de congestion, d'encombrements vont apparaître. Une autre conséquence est la dispersion des habitants des villes dans l'espace rural et ce pour une question de bien-être. Actuellement, 75\% des Belges vivent dans un habitat de type individuel et seulement un tiers de ces habitations sont mitoyennes. {\footnotesize D'après "CéMathèques" dossier thématique n°20 (2007, 10)}\\

L'impact des réseaux routiers sur l'urbanisation des secteurs à proximité des grandes voies de communication est manifeste. Les terrains à proximité des voies d'accès des autoroutes sont très prisés. Dans ce contexte, pas d'alternatives possibles à la voiture puisqu'il n'y a pas ou peu d'autres modes de transport. Parallèlement, nous assistons à un immense gaspillage de l'espace. \\


\section{ A l'heure actuelle}


\section{  Vers des solutions}



\subsection{  Spécificités du milieu rural}


\subsection{  En province de Luxembourg}


\section{ En guise de solution}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Chapitre 1 - Partie 2 !!!!!

\chapter{Marche-en-Famenne}


\section{Un peu d'histoire }

\subsection{Naissance de la ville }

\subsection{Période industrielle } 



\subsection{Période postindustrielle  }


\section{ Rénovation urbaine}

\section{ Rénovation et/ou revitalisation urbaine?}
\section{ Les acteurs du changement}

\section{ Le logement}

\section{ Aménagement du territoire et mobilité}

\section{La mobilité et le Boulevard urbain}
\label{mob et boule}

\subsection{La mobilité}
\subsection{Le Boulevard urbain (Ville de Marche, Fonds Européen de Développement Régional, Région wallonne, Maître d'ouvrage: M.E.T.)}
\section{ L'art et la nature en ville }
\section{ Une économie en croissance }
\section{ D'un point de vue architecture}
\section{ L'avenir de la ville}



\section{ D'autres projets à venir}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\part{}

\chapter{Tableau}
\section{Lipsum}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

My problems ([PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttdv6czwl5g35rb/Gonzalo.pdf)):

- Vertical stripe on the second page. How can I delete a vertical stripe on a wanted page?
- Missing "Table des matières" in the vertial stripe on page 4.
- The name of the latest chapter appears, sometimes, on the first page of a new chapter (for ex. page 7). What I want: something like on pages 13-14.

Comment: What should be the grey strip's width?

Comment: About 2 cm width

Comment: @Mathias: This is something like a thumbindex?

Comment: No, it is just to have a nice layout.

Comment: @Mathias: I think this is a question for Gonzalo Medina and his knowledge of TikZ ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see that you know me well :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: No, I just heard of it ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An option using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). Adjust the settings according to your needs:

An image of a single page of the result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\ChapterShift
\newlength\PageShift
\newlength\StripeWd

% the verticle shift for the chapter title from the upper border of the page
\setlength\ChapterShift{2cm}
% the vertical shift for the page number from the lower border of the page
\setlength\PageShift{2cm}
% the width of the vertical stripe
\setlength\StripeWd{2cm}

% the color of the stripe
\colorlet{StripeColor}{gray!60}

% the font for chapter title in the stripe
\def\ChapterFont{\color{white}\LARGE\sffamily}
% the font for page number in the stripe
\def\PageFont{\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}{}}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[OR]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[StripeColor]
  (current page.north east)
    rectangle
  ([xshift=-\StripeWd]current page.south east);
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north west,
  font=\ChapterFont,
  rotate=-90
]
  at ([xshift=-0.4\StripeWd,yshift=-\ChapterShift]current page.north east)
  {\leftmark};
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north,
  font=\PageFont,
]
  at ([xshift=-0.5\StripeWd,yshift=\PageShift]current page.south east)
  {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[EL]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[StripeColor]
  (current page.north west)
    rectangle
  ([xshift=\StripeWd]current page.south west);
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=south east,
  font=\ChapterFont,
  rotate=90
]
  at ([xshift=0.6\StripeWd,yshift=-\ChapterShift]current page.north west)
  {\leftmark};
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north,
  font=\PageFont,
]
  at ([xshift=0.5\StripeWd,yshift=\PageShift]current page.south west)
  {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Main Result and a longer title}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

An image of the complete document:

[image]

### Remarks:

Several auxiliary lengths and commands were defined so the attributes can be easily controlled; in particular:

- `\ChapterShift` controls the verticle shift for the chapter title from the upper border of the page; default value of `2cm`.
- `\PageShift` controls the vertical shift for the page number from the lower border of the page; default is `2cm`.
- `\StripeWd` controls the width of the vertical stripe; default value of `2cm`.
- `StripeColor` controls the color of the stripe; set by default to `gray!60`.
- `\ChapterFont` control the font for chapter title in the stripe; default of `\color{white}\LARGE\sffamily`.
- `\PageFont` controls the font for page number in the stripe; default value of `\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries`.

### Update after the edit:

```
% !TEX encoding = IsoLatin
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1.5ex} % Set the length of skip below the caption


\usepackage{chngpage} %Allows for temporary adjustment of side margins when the tables are to wide


% Just makes the table prettier (see \toprule, \bottomrule, etc. commands below)
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow} % multirows in tables

% Dimensions of the page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[papersize={210mm,210mm},top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{subfigure}

% For the lateral stripe 
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{colortbl,hhline}


\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection .\alph{subsubsection}}

% ========== Table of contents ========== 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks, % emp?É¬É?Ç¬©cher latex de colorer les liens
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black, % couleur des liens dans la table des matières
    urlcolor=blue
}

% Dots in the TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % Ligne of dots in the TOC
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at begin picture={
   \shorthandoff{:;!?};}
}}

% Give the same layout than the chapters to the TOC 
 \makeatletter
\def\@cftmaketoctitle{\chapter*{\contentsname}}
\makeatother
%___________________________________________

% ========== No number to the "part" pages ==========
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother
%___________________________________________


% ========== Layout of the chapters ==========

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
% ----- Case without "\chapter{}" -----
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \newpage 
  \mbox{~}     
  \vfill %
    {\parindent \z@ \reset@font
            \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    %\vspace*{1\p@}%
    \color{orange}{\hrulefill}
    \par\nobreak
    %\vskip 100\p@
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  }
  % Vertical stripe
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[orange]
  (current page.north east)
    rectangle
  ([xshift=-\StripeWd]current page.south east);
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north west,
  font=\ChapterFont,
  rotate=-90
]
  at ([xshift=-0.4\StripeWd,yshift=-\ChapterShift]current page.north east)
  {\leftmark};
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north,
  font=\PageFont,
]
  at ([xshift=-0.5\StripeWd,yshift=\PageShift]current page.south east)
  {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
    \newpage
}

% ----- Case with "\chapter*{}" -----
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \newpage 
  \mbox{~}     
  \vfill %
    {\parindent \z@ \reset@font
            \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    %\vspace*{1\p@}%
    \color{orange}{\hrulefill}
    \par\nobreak
    %\vskip 100\p@
  }
% Vertical stripe
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[orange]
  (current page.north east)
    rectangle
  ([xshift=-\StripeWd]current page.south east);
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north,
  font=\PageFont,
]
  at ([xshift=-0.5\StripeWd,yshift=\PageShift]current page.south east)
  {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
}

%___________________________________________

% ========== Vertical stripe to every page ==========
% Vertical stripe to every page of a chapter except the first page, with the name of the chapter and the page number written in it
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newlength\ChapterShift
\newlength\PageShift
\newlength\StripeWd

% the vertical shift for the chapter title from the upper border of the page
\setlength\ChapterShift{2cm}
% the vertical shift for the page number from the lower border of the page
\setlength\PageShift{2cm}
% the width of the vertical stripe
\setlength\StripeWd{2cm}

% the color of the stripe
\colorlet{StripeColor}{gray!60}

% the font for chapter title in the stripe
\def\ChapterFont{\color{white}\Large\sffamily}
% the font for page number in the stripe
\def\PageFont{\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}{}}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[OR]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[StripeColor]
  (current page.north east)
    rectangle
  ([xshift=-\StripeWd]current page.south east);
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north west,
  font=\ChapterFont,
  rotate=-90
]
  at ([xshift=-0.4\StripeWd,yshift=-\ChapterShift]current page.north east)
  {\leftmark};
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north,
  font=\PageFont,
]
  at ([xshift=-0.5\StripeWd,yshift=\PageShift]current page.south east)
  {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[EL]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[StripeColor]
  (current page.north west)
    rectangle
  ([xshift=\StripeWd]current page.south west);
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=south east,
  font=\ChapterFont,
  rotate=90
]
  at ([xshift=0.6\StripeWd,yshift=-\ChapterShift]current page.north west)
  {\leftmark};
\node[
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=north,
  font=\PageFont,
]
  at ([xshift=0.5\StripeWd,yshift=\PageShift]current page.south west)
  {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

%___________________________________________




\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\title{Title page}

\maketitle


\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\hfill
\vfill
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm} r}
Avant toute chose, je tiens à remercier sincèrement ma co-promotrice, Madame Bernadette Merenne; et mon promoteur, Monsieur Pierre Frankignoulle; pour leur disponibilité, leur implication, leurs nombreux conseils et l'attention qu'ils ont portés à ce travail. \newline

J'adresse également mes remerciements à toutes les personnes qui m'ont aidée de près ou de loin dans la réalisation de mes recherches et dans le travail d'analyse et de synthèse de mes différentes interviews.\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Monsieur Tielman et Madame Roosen pour leurs multiples interventions;
\item Les lecteurs de ce mémoire pour avoir accepté cette tâche;
\item Les nombreuses personnes interrogées pour leur implication et leur enthousiasme;
\item Ma famille et mes amis qui m'ont aidée et soutenue durant l'élaboration de ce travail.
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}


\newpage
 \tableofcontents
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\markboth{TABLE DES MATIERES}{}}

\newpage 

\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{INTRODUCTION}{}
\section*{Motivation}

\lipsum[1-5]

\section*{Objectif}


\section*{Méthodologie}
\subsection*{Sujet}


\subsection*{Manière de procéder} 


\newpage 
\empty

\part{}
\chapter{Mobilité et aménagement, un problème croissant}

\section{Quelques définitions}

\subsection{Mobilité}


\subsection{Développement urbain}

\section{Un peu d'histoire}

Le couple agglomération - réseau viaire ne date pas d'aujourd'hui. Un grand nombre de villages et villes se sont développés à la croisée de voies de communication; points d'échanges marchands, culturels, intellectuels, etc.\\

Au cours du XIXe siècle, la création des tramways et la pénétration du chemin de fer favorisent un développement de l'espace urbain à proximité des points d'arrêts de leurs lignes respectives. L'espace public reste en lien avec l'échelle du piéton. La banlieue, qui était déjà présente avant l'ère de l'automobile, se déployait en effet en fonction des axes de transport en commun. La ville demeurait compacte; son étendue était plutôt réduite et sa fonction principalement un lieu d'habitation dense et multifonctionnel. \\

En Belgique, à la fin du XIXe siècle, les chemins de fer vicinaux ont encouragé la construction de logements à l'extérieur des grandes villes et ont densifié un grand nombre de petits villages existants.\\

Après la guerre, l'expansion de l'automobile a contribué à l'étalement des villes en favorisant la fragmentation  du territoire et à la dispersion des diverses activités. Ce phénomène donne naissance à la ville diffuse avec la création de tracés routiers conçus sur base d'une hiérarchisation des voies de circulation.\\

Rapidement des problèmes de congestion, d'encombrements vont apparaître. Une autre conséquence est la dispersion des habitants des villes dans l'espace rural et ce pour une question de bien-être. Actuellement, 75\% des Belges vivent dans un habitat de type individuel et seulement un tiers de ces habitations sont mitoyennes. {\footnotesize D'après "CéMathèques" dossier thématique n°20 (2007, 10)}\\

L'impact des réseaux routiers sur l'urbanisation des secteurs à proximité des grandes voies de communication est manifeste. Les terrains à proximité des voies d'accès des autoroutes sont très prisés. Dans ce contexte, pas d'alternatives possibles à la voiture puisqu'il n'y a pas ou peu d'autres modes de transport. Parallèlement, nous assistons à un immense gaspillage de l'espace. \\


\section{ A l'heure actuelle}


\section{  Vers des solutions}



\subsection{  Spécificités du milieu rural}


\subsection{  En province de Luxembourg}


\section{ En guise de solution}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Chapitre 1 - Partie 2 !!!!!

\chapter{Marche-en-Famenne}


\section{Un peu d'histoire }

\subsection{Naissance de la ville }

\subsection{Période industrielle } 



\subsection{Période postindustrielle  }


\section{ Rénovation urbaine}

\section{ Rénovation et/ou revitalisation urbaine?}
\section{ Les acteurs du changement}

\section{ Le logement}

\section{ Aménagement du territoire et mobilité}

\section{La mobilité et le Boulevard urbain}
\label{mob et boule}

\subsection{La mobilité}
\subsection{Le Boulevard urbain (Ville de Marche, Fonds Européen de Développement Régional, Région wallonne, Maître d'ouvrage: M.E.T.)}
\section{ L'art et la nature en ville }
\section{ Une économie en croissance }
\section{ D'un point de vue architecture}
\section{ L'avenir de la ville}



\section{ D'autres projets à venir}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\part{}

\chapter{Tableau}
\section{Lipsum}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The answers to the new questions:

1. Use `\thispagestyle{plain}` for those pages (see the code above).
2. Use

   ```
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\markboth{TABLE DES MATIERES}{}}
   ```
3. In the definition of  `\@makeschapterhead`, suppress the node containing the mark (see code above).
4. Your example code produces errors due to loading `subfigure` and `tocloft`. Do not use `subfigure` which is an obsolete package; use `subcaption` instead.

Comment: I would put those `tikzpicture`s as commands so that the code is more clear when setting it up, e.g., something like `\fancyhead[OR]{\ORprintrule}` and `\fancyhead[EL]{\ELprintrule}`.

Comment: @Manuel might be. In this particular case, I don't see any great advantage in doing so, though.

Comment: Not really an advantage but just clarity. I always feel bad when the argument to a command is loooong (may be a bit maniac). (Ah, it's horrible to explain “feelings” in another language :D)

Comment: Thanks a lot Gonzalo, that's exactly what I was looking for.
Only one problem, when I use this formulation "\chapter*{Introduction}" for a chapter, the name of the chapter doesn't appear in the vertical stripe anymore.
Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Mathias You're welcome! Regarding starred chapters, the problem is that they don't automatically generate the marks used for the "headers"; you can use `\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{Introduction}{}`. Of course, the vertical stripes don't appear in the first page of a chapter (the title of the chapter is there already so the stripe might be redundant), but this can also be easily changed if you so desire. Please let me know.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks again, it works.
Other problems:
- Which code line do I have to add if I don't want a vertical stripe on a page (first pages of the book for example)?
- I composed my one first page of a chapter [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vybbly8psgrp2pr/Latex.pdf).
Unfortunately, sometimes the name of the latest chapter appears in the first page of the new chapter. What I want is just the orange stripe with nothing written in it.

Comment: @Mathias In this case, the best thing to do would be for you to open a follow-up question and add there a little, yet *complete* example document (like the one in my answer), showing the relevant settings and allowing us to reproduce the problem, so a solution can be provided.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I edited my first post with a complet exemple.

Comment: @Mathias please see my updated answer; the last section answers your questions. By the way, as I said before, it would've been better to open a fresh new question with these new issues, but I answered them here in any case.

Answer (score 18):

With `fancyhdr`, but without `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
  a5paper,
%  showframe,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Remove prefix "Chapter" and chapter number
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@fancy}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{}%
  {}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \protect\ps@headings}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\myouterheadwidth}
\setlength{\myouterheadwidth}{3em}
\newlength{\myouterheadsep}
\setlength{\myouterheadsep}{2em}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[RO]{%
  \hfill
  \rlap{%
    \kern\myouterheadsep
    \myouterhead
  }%
}
\fancyfoot[LE]{%
  \llap{%
    \myouterhead
    \kern\myouterheadsep
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\myouterhead}{%
  \sffamily\bfseries\Large
  \color{white}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(0, \dimexpr \footskip + \textheight + \headheight + \headsep
                     + \topmargin + 1in - \paperheight\relax){%
      \textcolor{lightgray}{\rule{\myouterheadwidth}{\paperheight}}%
    }%
    \put(0,\dimexpr\footskip + \textheight\relax){%
      \makebox(\myouterheadwidth,0)[t]{%
        \rotatebox{\ifodd\value{page}-\fi 90}{\leftmark}%
      }%
    }%
    \put(0,0){%
      \makebox(\myouterheadwidth,0)[b]{\thepage}%
    }%
  \end{picture}%
  \kern\myouterheadwidth
}

% Using same page style for chapter start pages, which use \pagestyle{plain}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]  [image: Page 2]